# JPA 2.0 + SPRING 3.1 + Weblogic 10.3.5

Tags: spring, jpa, weblogic

I need create a website in weblogic container, but i don´t know how to connected jpa 2.0 to jndi weblogic connection and management with spring.

now i have one project but with errors, in this case my file setup are :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
  <persistence-unit name="unitPU" transaction-type="JTA">
    <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
    <jta-data-source>jdbc/fact</jta-data-source>
    <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
    <properties>
      <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation" value="drop-and-create-tables"/>
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

and the error is:

```
weblogic.deployment.EnvironmentException: Error processing persistence unit unitPU of module web: Error instantiating the Persistence Provider class org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider of the PersistenceUnit factory-web-copyPU: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider
```

any sample or any idea to help me to solved this error o create a project jpa + spring + weblogic i will be greatful

Answer (score 0):

You haven't got the class: `org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider` in your classpath. That is what is causing the exception. So add the `.jar` file containing this class into your classpath or if you are using Maven add this dependency:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
   <artifactId>{artifact}</artifactId>
   <version>{version}</version>
   <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

And specify the appropriate `artifactId`.

**See:**

- [EclipseLink/Maven](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Maven)